# Контент сообщения пустой disnake

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Помогите пожалуйста. Второй день пытаюсь решить данную проблему с библиотекой disnake. При обработке события on_message хочу получить содержимое сообщения, однако вместо этого лишь пустое значение.
Запускаю на Python 3.11. Все библиотеки последние. Слэш команды работаю. Непосредственно на событие реагирует.

```
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
```

Comment: [Включите и выдайте намерения](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: @denisnumb все, понял. В коде забыл указать. Спасибо большое.